# What is a proper way to deal with Vue.js props that from the response of backend

Tags: vue.js

I am wondering that what is a proper way to deal with props in Vue.js if the prop is from the response of backend?

Ok, let's say the child component has a `prop` called `person`. a `name` is in person object.

```
    <template>
      {{ person.name }}
    <template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'ChildComponent',
        props:['person'],
        created(){
           this.getName();
        },
        data(){return{name:''}},
        methods:{
          getName(){
             this.name = this.person.name;
          }
    }

    </script>
```

The parent component is like this

```
    <template>
      <ChildComponent :person="person"></ChildComponent>
    <template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'ParentComponent',
        created(){
           this.getPerson();
        }
        data(){
          return {
             person: null
          }
        },
        methods:{getPerson(){
          // send request to server or api then update name 
          sendrequest().then(person => { this.person = person});
       }}
    </script>
```

At first, before the get the response, there will be a warning `can't get name from person`.
I know 2 methods to handle this:

1. `<ChildComponent :person="person" v-if="person"></ChildComponent>`
2. watch `person` prop in, every time the person is changed, rerun the getName() method in childcomponent or set name as a computed attribute.

So here is the question again, are they the proper way to handle this? Is there still some other methods like using Vuex?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case, if you don't want to show the person until it is ready then `v-if` seems like the right way to go.

If you want to display something until the person object is ready you have 2 options:

1. Give person a default name, or init it with an empty name
2. show a loading component until person is ready

Answer (score 0):

This is not vue warning. Basically this is javascript error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`, which vue may show you as warning. Your 1 variant is okey. Same as `<div v-if="person">{{person.name}}</div>` in your child. Also you may fill your person with some thing like

```
return {
  person: {name: 'loading...'}
}
```

and in your parent

```
mounted: function () {
  // your person will be loaded when component mounted
  this.getPerson() 
}
```